# change the table name that is under subscription

Tags: kdb

I have an engine that subscribes to the TP.
The table name in TP is called TradeTab.
When I subscribe in the engine I would like the table to be called TradeRec.
How could this be done?

```
h(`.u.sub;`TradeTab;`long$til 10)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would need to update your `upd` function which your tickerplant will call in your subscriber process, which is used to insert data into your tables.

You can do this in various ways, e.g. use a dictionary where `TradeTab` is mapped to `TradeRec`, though you would need a mapping for each table being subscribed to.

```
upd:{
  d:enlist[`TradeTab]!enlist `TradeRec;
  d[x] insert y
 }
```

Or you could use a conditional, the following would only map `TradeTab` to `TradeRec`, and the rest would be inserted into the given table name from the tickerplant.

```
upd:{
  $[`TradeTab=x;
    `TradeRec insert y;
    x insert y
   ];
 }
```

On top of this, the schema for your table would need to be called `TradeRec`, and match the schema to `TradeTab`.

If you are using the default `.u.sub` to create your empty table (using the empty table returned by it, e.g.

```
(set) . h(`.u.sub;`TradeTab;`)
```

You can change the name of the table using something like

```
(set) . `TradeRec,1_h(`.u.sub;`TradeTab;`)
```

Here, I am replacing the first item (the table name) in the list provided by the tickerplant with the table name you wish to rename it to.

Comment: thanks, but isn't the table TradeTab created at the moment .u.sub is called?

Comment: If you're using default `.u.sub`, then you can create the table from the output of TradeTab, but the way you subscribe would need to change to create the empty table with a new name of TradeRec, I'll add this to the answer

Comment: Wouldn't necessarily need a table mapping for all tables in the dictionary method. Could use fill `t:t^@[enlist[TradeTab]!enlist TradeRec;t]`